# How do I connect to a online database that is username-password protected?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database

I am currently working with an online database at a local server (but I don't have physical access to the server). I want to use python (version 3.5) to connect to the database and work with the data.

Since the problem is pretty early in the developing process I have not tried too much yet. In my mind I would like it to work somehow like this:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

db = sql.connect('localhost:port', 'username', 'password', 'database.db')
```

I expect it to return the database connection object I could then work with.

Comment: This depends on the Database you want to use. For your purposes, I would look into PostgreSQL, which is free and open source, It's syntax is similar to e.g. MySQL. You can't really use sqlite, which you used in your example, as an online database.

Comment: Of course, you could also use MySQL

Comment: thank you for the quick answer. I am now using a PostgreSQL database and it is doing it's job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need public IP of the VM/server where the database is hosted.

```
db = sql.connect('<PUBLIC_IP:PORT>', '<USER_NAME>', '<PASSWORD>', '<DATABASE>')
```

will get your requirement done. If it does not work, and you get connection error,
make sure that the port is correct.